# Clicking button did not work in view of backbone js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

I am newbie to backbone.js, I create a `contact form` and want to use it in several pages of my website. I am using `text.js` to make `html` file for each template of the project.

Here is `customer` view,  one of a view in my project, and add `contact form` in it :

```
define(["jquery" ,
    "underscore" ,
    "backbone" ,
    "text!templates/contact_tem.html"
],function($ , _ , Backbone, Contact){

  var customer = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize : function(){
    },
    el: '#customerdiv',
    render : function(){
        this.$el.empty();
        var _contact = _.template(Contact);
        this.$el.html("blah blah blah");
        $("#contactformhere").html(_contact);
    }
  });
  return customer;
});
```

Example, I have a button in `contact form` template, I don't want to handle `button` event in `customer` view, if I do so, I have to write the button event in every views of my project. Then I create a view, used for handle the `contact` form :

```
define(["jquery" ,
     "underscore" ,
     "backbone" ,
     "text!templates/contact_tem.html"
],function($ , _ , Backbone , Contact){
var contact = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize:function(){
        this.render();
    },
    event : {
        'click #testonContactForm' : 'hi'
    },
    hi : function(){
      alert("Hi");
    },
    render:function(){
        var _contact = _.template(Contact)
        this.$el.html(_contact);
    }
});
return contact;
});
```

`alert("hi")` in contact view is not working, any idea about it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing event for events

```
events : {
        'click #testonContactForm' : 'hi'
    }
```

http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents

Hope this helps

Comment: It is my bad typo, sorry.